# RecordMyDesktop video and sound off?

Tags: recordmydesktop

so with RecordMyDesktop for some odd reason it is fast forwarding the video and slowing the sound the two are not matching up at all. so can some one tell me how to fix it or what to use to fix the speed of the video?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469103) this might be due to your computer being too slow. Try disabling "Encode On The Fly":

> I had it as "Encode On The Fly" but changed it to 'Zero Compression'. Although it takes a while to encode after recording, at least now it work as it suppose to be.